# how should i read an audio clip in a java program?

Tags: java, audio, variable-assignment

I am a beginner at java and i wanna know how to read an audio clip in a program, i am referring to a thread that makes an image to move, because this read an image and thinking if that would be similar to reading an audio clip but then wonder how to read an audio clip.. i am really clueless... any sample would really help... thnx alot in advance :)

also... i am still not familiar with the keywords i should use... like for example in reading an image, i should be using -> ImageIO.read(new File("picture.gif"));

what about for the audio clip?

thanks again :)

Comment: What do you want to do with it once you read it?

Comment: like once i click a button i would hear a sound, or an introduction sound once i open the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. It is from an old project I did where I had to do simple audio playback. The classes are from `javax.sound.sampled` package. Mind you there are several ways of doing this, but this was the simplest I could find back then. You'll need to add a `try catch` block for `IOException`,`UnsupportedAudioFileException` and `LineUnavailableException` to wrap that code.

```
File afile = new File(audioFilePath);
AudioInputStream astream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(afile);
Clip audio = AudioSystem.getClip();
audio.open(astream);
audio.setFramePosition(0);
audio.start();
```